# spark-submit in hadoop kerberos with --proxy-user, --keytab and --principal parameter

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, kerberos, spark-submit

Just wanted to get clarification if
spark-submit --keytab --principal && --proxy-user parameters can coexist together?

We have a requirement to submit the job as a real business user but the user does not have principal in hadoop kdc.

I'm getting the exception whenever use proxy-user and kerberos principal them together.

```
17/02/09 13:51:43 INFO DFSClient: Created HDFS_DELEGATION_TOKEN token 379 for atlas on 10.12.118.92:8020
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:888)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.addDelegationTokens(KeyProviderDelegationTokenExtension.java:8
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.addDelegationTokens(DistributedFileSystem.java:2243)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:121)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:206)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:315)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1293)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1288)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1328)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1327)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine$lzycompute(CsvRelation.scala:269)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine(CsvRelation.scala:265)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.inferSchema(CsvRelation.scala:242)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.<init>(CsvRelation.scala:74)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:171)
        at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:158)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:119)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:109)
        at org.sandbox.Main$.main(Main.scala:39)
        at org.sandbox.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:163)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1672)
        at org.apache.hadoop.crypto.key.kms.KMSClientProvider.addDelegationTokens(KMSClientProvider.java:870)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, status: 403, message: Forbidde
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.AuthenticatedURL.extractToken(AuthenticatedURL.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.PseudoAuthenticator.authenticate(PseudoAuthenticator.java:77)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.token.delegation.web.DelegationTokenAuthenticator.authenticate(DelegationTokenAuthenticator.java:128
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.authentication.client.KerberosAuthenticator.authenticate(KerberosAuthenticator.java:214)
```

1. If the proxy-user and principal parameters can't be coexist together, do you guys have documentation about that ?
2. What will be the real use case of proxy-user parameter in kerberos hadoop environment ?

Comment: Typical cases of Hadoop "proxy users" are `oozie` (a job scheduler) and `hue` (a gateway UI) -- they can launch jobs for you, without requiring your password. Without you being connected, in the case of Oozie.

Answer (score 3):

When making spark-submit --keytab,  --principal && --proxy-user parameters can't be used together.

If used together submit will through following error:

Spark submit failed:
Error: Only one of --proxy-user or --principal can be provided.

[image]

Comment: For anyone who wants to see the Jira/discussion on when this combination was disallowed: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13478

Answer (score 0):

1) `--proxy-user` and `--principal` [can't be passed together to `spark-submit`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmitArguments.scala#L262) at the same time. However you can initialize as a kerberos user and launch spark-job under proxy-user:

`kinit -kt USER.keytab USER && spark-submit --proxy-user PROXY-USER`

* It won't work if you use spark with hive + make sure you have `hadoop.proxyuser.USER.{hosts,groups}` configured correctly.

2) [A superuser with username ‘super’ wants to submit job and access hdfs on behalf of a user joe. The superuser has kerberos credentials but user joe doesn’t have any. The tasks are required to run as user joe and any file accesses on namenode are required to be done as user joe. It is required that user joe can connect to the namenode or job tracker on a connection authenticated with super’s kerberos credentials. In other words super is impersonating the user joe.](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html#Use_Case)

Comment: I'm still getting the same exception even i do kinit first and remove principal and keytab during spark-submit. Any idea ?

Comment: See here for full discussion.  This combination used to be allowed in old versions.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13478

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to use --proxy-user, --principal  and --keytab together using spark submit. The problem above is due to DELEGATIONTOKEN request permission to KMS Ranger.

So i have added following entry in "Custom kms site" to make it works.

```
hadoop.kms.proxyuser.xxx.users=*
hadoop.kms.proxyuser.xxx.hosts=*
```